# Haskell hGetContents not reading data written with external program

Tags: haskell

I am opening a file handle with `openFile`, writing data to it using `ByteString.hPutStrLn`, and then opening the file in an external editor.  I seek the handle back to the beginning of the file with `hSeek` and expect to read back in the changes made with the external editor.  However I am not seeing the changes made in the external editor.  Example:

```
module Main where

import System.Process
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- openFile "myfile" ReadWriteMode
  BS.hPutStrLn handle . BS.pack $ "hello"
  hFlush handle
  callProcess "vi" ["myfile"]
  hSeek handle AbsoluteSeek 0
  str' <- BS.hGetContents handle
  BS.putStr str'
```

All that ever gets printed to my terminal is "hello" no matter what changes I make while in vi.  However, if I then examine the file, the changes are there.  Why isn't `hGetContents` seeing the changes?

Comment: Pehaps the Haskell executable is just *buffering* the older contents. See [doc here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html#io.buffering). Did you try with the`NoBuffering` option ?

Comment: I get the same result if I add `hSetBuffering handle NoBuffering` before the `BS.hGetContents`.

Comment: My guess is that `vi` saves by deleting the old file and creating a new one with the same name. E.g. it saves to a temp file and then atomically overwrites the original file -- this is due to ensure that in the case of a crash (such as power failure) no data is completely lost. Your haskell code then keeps on accessing the "ghost file": unix keeps the old overwritten file semi-alive until it is closed. You won't see the new data on that ghost file.

Comment: @chi is probably right. This can be verified by trying to do the same thing in another language of your choice and seeing if you get the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

The editor is creating a new file when it saves, and the handle in Haskell is reading from the old file.  My editor was going to Vim which has the `writebackup` feature set by default.

Turning off `writebackup` results in the behavior I expected, as did using `ed`.